# How to Remember the Difference Between Effective and Affective?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's an easy way to remember when to use “affect” or “effect”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24037/whats-an-easy-way-to-remember-when-to-use-affect-or-effect)
>   [Effect vs. Affect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect)

I always confuse the two and I have no way of telling them apart! Help!

Comment: Note the related question: [“What’s an easy way to remember when to use *affect* or *effect*?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24037/whats-an-easy-way-to-remember-when-to-use-affect-or-effect) <hr> Mnemonics are hard to provide because they depend so much on your particular background, personal knowledge, and what exactly it is you don't understand. I'll try anyway: **something *effective* produces *effects***. ***Affective* is related to *affection* and other feelings**.