# How to explain the difference between "affect" and "effect"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I don't know how to explain the difference between *effect* and *affect* to someone. I've tried explaining that *effect* is a noun, and *affect* is a verb, that *to affect* is to make a change, and *effect* is the change that was made, but these explanations haven't made sense. (They're 17 and very intelligent, so please don't be rude.) Could you please suggest other ways of explaining this?

Comment: This link may help: http://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/affect-effect/

Comment: Can they use "special effects" as a mnemonic device? Clearly "effects" is a noun in "special effects", and these are the tangible, concrete  elements of a movie -- things you can literally see and hear -- that make it memorable.

Comment: @LeoKing Can you describe the problem they're having any further? Is it about remembering which is which? Is it that they're having trouble with the noun/verb distinction itself?

Comment: They're not sure, but I've shown them this question and hopefully they can give me more information about what they don't understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Effect" vs. "Affect"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/effect-vs-affect)

Comment: The accepted answer is the the noun-verb distinction which wasn't sufficient. I was hoping this question could provide some alternative methods of explaining the difference.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0001-affectvseffect.html

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24037/13924 may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Part of your problem is that both _affect_ and _effect_ can be nouns and both _affect_ and _effect_ can be verbs—so trying to distinguish between the two words by presenting one as a noun and the other as a verb is incomplete at best.

Comment: Setting aside complexity as much as possible, I would focus on memorizing the main idea underlying each of the four terms: _affect_ (n.) "sign of a person's emotional state"; _effect_ (n.) "consequence"; _affect_ (v.) "influence"; _effect_ (v.) "cause or accomplish". I acknowledge that the fact that in English _effect_ can mean "cause" is somewhat mind-boggling.

Answer (score 3):

*Effect* can be a noun meaning *the consequence of an action*.

> This drug has powerful **effects**.

It can also be a verb meaning *to bring about*.

> The new principal **effected** many changes.

*Affect* can be an uncountable noun meaning *the observable expression of emotion* in psychology.

> People with mental problems may have different **affect**.

It can also be a verb meaning *make a difference to*.

> His presence **affects** her a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the best way to memorize these very lightly different words is to associate them to something else that they would remember. You want to trigger this association so every time the moment arises that they need to use one, they can think for a moment and remember their [mnemonic](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Mnemonic.htm).

Since *affect* and *effect* are only one letter difference, try having that letter be what you grow off of.

Use:

(**A**)ffect when you want to apply, alter, adjust things.
You impact something else in a way. You're the cause.

(**E**)ffect when an it is the event (*sort of*). An explosion!
This is the outcome of what you've done. What you see. The result.

> "I *affected* this firecracker by lighting it on fire, now wait for the *effect* when it explodes."

I'll try to come back and list more that comes to mind, but the logic is still the same that you need to make that connection that this word is like another.

(Sorry for the sloppiness, I'll likely revise this a few times within the next day)