# When to use Affect and effect?

Tags: vocabulary

i had a hard time in using these similar looking words at appropriate places.
some help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: or of this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24037/whats-an-easy-way-to-remember-when-to-use-affect-or-effect

Comment: It's also one of [the most discussed English topics on the internet](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/affect.html). I vote "general reference", here.

Comment: i read both, none helps exactly.

Comment: @Iamnikhil08, after reading those answers, what is still unclear to you?

Comment: None came up with an illustration, and also there answers were rather confusing

Comment: i read on some website the difference between these words, but couldn't find it now.

Comment: sorry, My mistake.. good responses were there on those links, but those show up when i scroll down. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

*Affect* is a verb and *effect* is a noun. So for example:

> The drought affected the growth of the economy.
>
> The drought had a great effect on the growth of the economy.

However, it gets more complicated: *effect* can also be used as a verb, which means to bring about. This is rarer, though, and mostly used in formal English. For example:

> The Fed effected the rise of interest rates.